# Remove nan value from dictionary and list using python

Tags: python, json

I want to remove nan value from dictonaires  and list. If nan is the only value in case of phone_type work then remove full dictionary itself.

**Input Data**

```
dic = {'Customer_Number': 12345, 'Email': [{'Email_Type': 'Primary', 'Email': ['sa@ru.edu', nan]}]
,'Phone_Number': [{'Phone_Type': 'Mobile', 'Phone': [1217]}, {'Phone_Type': 'work', 'Phone': [nan]}]}
```

**Expected Output**

```
{'Customer_Number': 12345, 'Email': [{'Email_Type': 'Primary', 'Email': ['sam@rus.edu']}]
,'Phone_Number': [{'Phone_Type': 'Mobile', 'Phone': [1217]}]}
```

**Code tried:**

```
for i in range(0, len(dic)):
    for j in dic[i][key]:
       print("j key:",j)
       print("j",j[value[1]])
       if (pd.isna(j[value[1]])):
           print("nan condition")
           dic[i][value[1]].remove(j)
       else:
           null_val_dict_removal.append(j)
   dic[i][key] = null_val_dict_removal
   print("dict key", dic[i][key])
   null_val_dict_removal = []
```

**Getting error :**

```
if (pd.isna(j[value[1]])):
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a recursive function to remove `nan` and empty lists/dictionaries:

```
import json
from numpy import nan, NaN, NAN

dic = {'Customer_Number': 92154246, 'Email': [{'Email_Type': 'Primary', 'Email': ['saman.zonouz@rutgers.edu', nan]}]
,'Phone_Number': [{'Phone_Type': 'Mobile', 'Phone': [12177218280.0]}, {'Phone_Type': 'work', 'Phone': [nan]}]}

# define which elements you want to remove:
to_be_deleted = [[], {}, "", None, nan]

def remove_empty_elements(jsonData):
    if isinstance(jsonData, list):
        jsonData = [new_elem for elem in jsonData
                    if (new_elem := remove_empty_elements(elem)) not in to_be_deleted]
   
    elif isinstance(jsonData,dict):
        jsonData = {key: new_value for key, value in jsonData.items()
                    if (new_value := remove_empty_elements(value)) not in to_be_deleted}
        if len(jsonData) == 1:
            return None

    return jsonData

new_dic = remove_empty_elements(dic)

print(json.dumps(new_dic, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
    "Customer_Number": 92154246,
    "Email": [
        {
            "Email_Type": "Primary",
            "Email": [
                "saman.zonouz@rutgers.edu"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Phone_Number": [
        {
            "Phone_Type": "Mobile",
            "Phone": [
                12177218280.0
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

###### Edit: for python < 3.8, remove the comprehension assignments from the function:

```
def remove_empty_elements(jsonData):
    if isinstance(jsonData, list):
        jsonData = [remove_empty_elements(elem) for elem in jsonData
                    if remove_empty_elements(elem) not in to_be_deleted]
   
    elif isinstance(jsonData,dict):
        jsonData = {key: remove_empty_elements(value) for key, value in jsonData.items()
                    if remove_empty_elements(value) not in to_be_deleted}
        if len(jsonData) == 1:
            return None

    return jsonData
```

Comment: In input data we can't put np.nan. It will come as i have given in input data.

Comment: It has to be a reference to `numpy.nan` though, otherwise the declaration of your dictionary is invalid. I edited the code to make it work with `nan` (importing `nan` from `numpy`)

Comment: Walrus operator is not working in pyton 3.7 getting error "python version 3.7 does not support assignment expressions"

Comment: added the solution for python < 3.8. try to update if you can!

Comment: there is little change. We have Nan given the format here and code is not working for that : {
                "Phone_Type": "work",
                "Phone": [
                    NaN
                ]
            }

Comment: changed the code to include `NaN` and `NAN` as well ;-) please try to include a more extensive example next time! (and specify your python version)

Comment: I am sorry for last moment changes. I am coming across those changes with the time.

Comment: You have updated the code for phone number. Actually that will not work bcz code will not be configurable in that case. I have just taken the sample. that issue can come across  any number of column.

Comment: like phone_type and phone_number there can be more field like email etc.

Comment: I want to remove all dict which has only 'nan' value.

Comment: Well `{'Phone_Type': 'work', 'Phone': [nan]}]}` doesn't have only `nan` values but you want it gone too right? I've edited the code to remove dictionaries where only one element remains (like `{'Phone_Type': 'work'}`), check it out!

Comment: It is not removing NaN values. I think we have considered as String value. May be that is the reason it is not removing Nan values

Comment: Hard to follow what you're talking about. The NaN values are removed in the example of my answer with the provided code. Are you data different? please update your question with actual data!

Comment: I am working on same data but it is not deleting nan or NaN values

Comment: did you try with my whole code (not forgetting `from numpy import nan, NaN, NAN` or `to_be_deleted = [[], {}, "", None, nan]`)? Does the code run without error?

Comment: let me try this.. I didn't import from numpy

Comment: I have included import numpy . It is running without any error but not removing Nan/nan values

Comment: `nan` values should be removed correctly, you can check it out here: https://onlinegdb.com/UyhvuRzob

Comment: let me check again. Might me some other issue

Comment: Checked everything but not working for me

Comment: I got the issue. It is not working for phone number and for email it is perfectly working fine. some of the phone_number showing as float value.

Comment: If you add an excerpt of the non working data to the question we can surely adapt the answer